# How to tell new-object is from which version of assembly?

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly

In PowerShell, I use the following code to load two assemblies

```
#sql server 2012 assembly
add-type -assembly "microsoft.sqlserver.smo, version=11.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91";
#sql server 2017 assembly
add-type -assembly "microsoft.sqlserver.smo, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91";
```

and I can see both assemblies are loaded successfully

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | where location -like "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\microsoft.sqlserver.smo*"
```

[image]

Now if I have the following code

```
$svr = new-object "microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server" 'localhost';
```

Does this **$svr** come from SQL Server 2012 assembly (version 11.0.0.0) or from SQL Server 2017 assembly (version 14.0.0.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type will be loaded from the first assembly which you load. To see the assembly of type you can use following code:

```
$svr.GetType().Assembly.FullName
```

If you want to see the difference, you can test a different order in a new PowerShell session.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Vote as an answer. Thanks Reza.